# python argparse separate 2 options of comamnds

Tags: python, argparse

I've read the documentation but still can't figure out how to achieve the following behavior:
1.likes. Give a specified number of likes to users in a tinder (in the future, this may contain more options, such as "gender", "frequency", "age", etc.)
2. Write a given text to a given number of people on tinder (in the future, there may also be more options).

There is my code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Badoo liker', epilog='Enjoy the program! :)')
# I also tried "add_mutually_exclusive_group" instead of "add_argument_group"
chat_args = parser.add_argument_group(title='chat_args')
chat_args.add_argument('-c', '--chat', help='chat help')
chat_args.add_argument('-t', '--text', help='text help')
chat_args.add_argument('-n', '--number', help='n help')

like_args = parser.add_argument_group(title='like_args')
like_args.add_argument('-l', '--like', help='like help')
like_args.add_argument('-n', '--number', help='n help')

args = parser.parse_args()

Usage:
$script.py chat --text 'Hello world' -n 20 # Var 1
$script.py liking -n 20 # Var 2
```

Obviously, I'm waiting for arguments either for a chat or either for liking

P.S. I'm getting an error because of `-n` common argument, but even if comment it it will not working as expecting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I did it, the next code is (apparently) meets my question

```
# "metavar=''" -just hide redundant double --key KEY word
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Badoo liker', epilog='Enjoy the program! :)')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='')

parser_like = subparsers.add_parser('like', help='like help')
parser_like.add_argument('-n', '--number', metavar='', help='Set count of likes', default=49)
parser_like.add_argument('-f', '--frequency', metavar='', help='Set chance to like/dislike', default=70)

parser_chat = subparsers.add_parser('chat', help='chat help')
parser_chat.add_argument('-n', '--number', metavar='', help='number help', required=True)
parser_chat.add_argument('-t', '--text', metavar='', help='text help', required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard to tell what you understand and what has worked or not for you.

This is more of a comment, but long enough that I'll make it answer.

Are those `usage` lines samples of what you use when calling this script?  What error(s) do you get?

Have you tried `scipt.py -h` to see the help?

I don't see a `positional` argument that would accept a string like "chat" or "liking".  I suspect you want to use the subcommands mechanism, but get the basic argparse working.

I often suggest including a `print(args)` line to get a clear idea of what the parser has done.  Though obviously you won't see that while `argparse` is raising errors.

Postpone the use of groups until you get the basics down.  `argument_group` just groups arguments in the help display.  `mutually_exclusive_group` is a parsing tool, that complains if you try to use more than one item in the group.

Comment: Thanks for hints about sub_parser and argument_group!